# SharePoint via SOAP using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, soap, suds

I have been following the solution noted here - as this is exactly what I need to achieve;

[how can i use sharepoint (via soap?) from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218987/how-can-i-use-sharepoint-via-soap-from-python)

however when I run one of the last lines of this code I get the following error;

`>>> client = SoapClient(url, {'opener' : opener})`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 456, in __init__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'options'
```

Any advice or suggestion as to how to solve this most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://fedorahosted.org/suds/browser/trunk/suds/client.py?rev=504

```
434     class SoapClient:
...
445         """
446     
447         def __init__(self, client, method):
448             """
449             @param client: A suds client.
450             @type client: L{Client}
451             @param method: A target method.
452             @type method: L{Method}
453             """
454             self.client = client
455             self.method = method
456             self.options = client.options
457             self.cookiejar = CookieJar()
```

The first parameter of `SoapClient` is not a `string` but an object of the `Client` class. Your parameter is not an instance of the required class.