# 403 Forbidden Error for Python-Suds contacting Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, suds

I'm using Python's SUDs lib to access Sharepoint web services.
I followed the standard doc from Suds's website. 
For the past 2 days, no matter which service I access, the remote service always returns 403 Forbidden.

I'm using Suds 0.4 so it has built-in support for accessing Python NTLM.

Let me know if anyone has a clue about this.

```
from suds import transport
from suds import client
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='USER_ID', password='PASS')
c_lists = client.Client(url='https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL', transport=ntlm)
#c_lists = client.Client(url='https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_vti_bin/spsearch.asmx?WSDL')

#print c_lists

listsCollection = c_lists.service.GetListCollection()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the username as `DOMAIN\USER_ID` as indicated in [examples for the python-ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/) library? (Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218987/how-can-i-use-sharepoint-via-soap-from-python/5403203#5403203)).

Comment: I learned about it later last night at one of the codes someone posted on the web. Problem was that I don't know what my DOMAIN is. Is it always just "DOMAIN" or is there some way I can find out what my domain is. I plan to contact the Sharepoint admin to find out. I know i'm not in the Admin group, but not sure which one I'm in.