# How to connect python to SharePoint with a mac friendly ntlm authentication

Tags: python, macos, sharepoint, soap, ntlm

I read this [how can i use sharepoint (via soap?) from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218987/how-can-i-use-sharepoint-via-soap-from-python)
 and is exactly what I need however, since I am using os x, I wanted to know how to go around the compatibility issue of using windows ntlm authentication.

Is there an easy way of connecting to SharePoint from python (through SOAP) using a mac friendly ntlm authentication?

Comment: a friendly heads up: you're entering a world of pain

Comment: thanks for the reply, have you done it before?

Comment: I think I solved it, if anyone has a similar question refer to this page {http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/} Utilizing this, it gives me the XML format of the sharepoint website I am trying to connect to which is what I needed.

Comment: I did several stuff, nothing exactly like you're describing. It was very painful. I eventually opted to ditch SharePoint at a certain point

Comment: I am supposed to connect and retrieve data from SharePoint as well as place data into sharepoint through python, it is actually getting a bit harder now that I am getting deeper into it.